# How to manage a dynamic amount of streamlit selectboxes?

Tags: python, streamlit

Im trying to create a web app that lets the user to add and remove selectboxes as he pleases.
I have an "Add" button that creates a new listbox and I would like to have next to each listbox a delete button to let the user remove that listbox.
I encounter two problems.

1. The remove button and listbox dont occupy the same amount of space and for that reason they are not alligned with each other
   (Will show it in a screenshot later on). Maybe there is a way to create a grid of these widgets to fix this issue?
2. When I press the remove button, I try to delete both the corresponding listbox and the remove button itself by their respective keys but nothing happens.
   Here is some code:

```
st.button("Add",on_click = callbacks.add_callback,help="Add a new test",  key="Add", args=(engine, tests_body_container,) )

def add_callback(engine, container):
      with container:
            col1, col2 = st.columns([1,1])
            st.session_state.test_count += 1
            for i in range(st.session_state.test_count):
                with col1:
                    st.selectbox(f"Test {i + 1}:", ("a", "b", "c"), key = "Test_" + str(i + 1))     
                with col2:
                    st.button("Remove", on_click = remove_callback, help="Remove this test",key="Remove_"+ str(i+1), args=("Test_" + str(i+1),"Remove_"+ str(i+1)))
```

```
def remove_callback(key_of_test, key_of_remove_button):
     del st.session_state[key_of_test]
     del st.session_state[key_of_remove_button]
     st.session_state.test_count -= 1
```

Here is the missallignment:
[image: missallignment]